# Undefined name 'FlutterAbsolutePath'

Tags: flutter, api, image-upload, imagepicker

I am developing a flutter mobile application where I need to upload multiple images through an API. Now I completed the part where pick images from the gallery. Next step is to upload the images. To do that I need the image path. I know that image path can be get by using the below code line but it keep saying that **Undefined name 'FlutterAbsolutePath'** what is the reason how to fix this issue. I am using multi-image-picker package.

```
final filePath =
          await FlutterAbsolutePath.getAbsolutePath(image.identifier);
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be really nice if you could provide us with some more information or even a code sample. In case you are using this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/multi_image_picker), I would strongly advice you to change it to one that is not discontinued (take a look into this one: [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker); you can select multiple images at once with this one too).

Until further information is provided you can take a look over the following code that uses the [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker):
After following the installation steps from the documentation you can get images using the next method:

```
Future<void> getImages() async {
  ImagePicker imagePicker = ImagePicker();

  List<XFile>? images = await imagePicker.pickMultiImage();

  if ((images ?? []).isNotEmpty) {
    //get the path of the first image from the select images
    String imagePath = images?.first.path ?? '';

    //get the content of the first image from the select images as bytes
    Uint8List? imageAsBytes = await images?.first.readAsBytes();

    //get the content of the first image from the select images as a String based on a given encoding
    String? imageAsString = await images?.first.readAsString();
  }
}
```

I hope that I helped you a little bit. Happy coding! :)

**Later edit:**

Here is a very basic Flutter app that picks an image with multi-picker, creates a temp file for which we know the *path* and displays the temp file in order to show that the temp file was correctly displayed.

For you, what's of most interest is getFile() method which takes care of creating the temp file that is 1:1 with picked image(s).

For creating the temp file I used: [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) also take a look into the following: [Read and write files](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files)

For permission handling: [permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler)

I still strongly suggest that you use other package for image picking as this one is discontinued :).

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:multi_image_picker/multi_image_picker.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

Future<File?> getFile() async {
  List<Asset> images = await MultiImagePicker.pickImages(maxImages: 100);

  if (images.isNotEmpty) {
    ByteData bytesData = await images.first.getByteData();
    List<int> bytes = bytesData.buffer
        .asUint8List(bytesData.offsetInBytes, bytesData.lengthInBytes)
        .cast<int>();

    //get the extension jpeg, png, jpg
    String extension = (images.first.name ?? '').split('.').last;

    //get path to the temporaryDirector
    final Directory directory = await getTemporaryDirectory();

    //get the path to the chosen directory
    String directoryPath = directory.path;

    //create a temporary file to the specified path
    //you can use the path to this file for the API
    File file = File('$directoryPath/myImage.$extension');

    //write the bytes to the image
    file.writeAsBytesSync(bytes, mode: FileMode.write);

    //just for path: file.path -> will return a String with the path
    return file;
  }
  return null;
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  File? file;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.amber,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          const SizedBox(
            height: 50,
          ),
          Center(
            child: TextButton(
              child: const Text('Pick an image'),
              onPressed: () async {
                await Permission.accessMediaLocation.request();
                file = await getFile();

                setState(() {});
              },
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 50,
          ),
          file != null
              ? Image.file(
                  file!,
                  height: 200,
                  width: 200,
                )
              : Container(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried that but there is a problem. I cannot select multiple images at once t takes multiple attempts

Comment: @IrushiNathashaKuruppu so you want something like sliding over the images to pick them?

Comment: what I want is like pick multiple images at once from your gallery and then save it to the database from an API :( all are working fine. the only problem is I can get the image path

Comment: @IrushiNathashaKuruppu please check the updated answer :)